# SAPUI5 Upload Collection Delete Not firing (UI5 lib 1.44)

Tags: sapui5, jscript, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I am trying to delete an image from an upload collection, once its updated in the backend system, but delete event is not firing, below is my code:

I have tried following this link,
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/645

but not solved my problem.

View

```
<UploadCollection 

    id="uploadCollection" 
    uploadUrl="/sap/opu/odata/sap/ODATA_SRV/AttachmentSet"
    items="{ path: 'Emp>/AttachmentSet', 
            filters: [{ path: 'Application', 
                        operator: 'EQ', 
                        value1: 'Test' }] }"
    uploadComplete="onAttachmentUploadComplete" 
    fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" 
    typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch"
    mimeType="image/jpeg,application/pdf,image/pjpeg" 
    maximumFileSize='2' 
    fileDeleted="onAttachmentDeleted" 
    change="onAttachmentChange"
    sameFilenameAllowed="false">

<UploadCollectionItem 
    contributor=""   enableDelete="true"
    documentId="{Emp>Filename}" 
    fileName="{Emp>Filename}" 
    fileSize=""
    mimeType="{Emp>MimeType}" 
    uploadedDate="" 
    url="{__metadata/media_src}" 
    enableEdit="false" 
    visibleEdit="false"/>

<headerParameters>

    <UploadCollectionParameter 
    name="x-csrf-token" 
    value="xyz"/>
</headerParameters>

<parameters/>
</UploadCollection>
```

Controller:

```
onAttachmentDeleted: function(e) {
 sap.m.MessageBox.Show("Test Alert");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi have you tried to include "enableDelete" property to true in UploadCollectionItem?

API Ref Below:

Enables/Disables the Delete button. If the value is true, the Delete button is enabled and the delete function can be used. If the value is false, the delete function is not available.

Comment: Thanks for the responses,

enableDelete functionality is set to true, 
the issue is delete event is not firing in the controller.
this is kind of known sap issue,
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/645
but cant find a solution.

Comment: hi in your code i don't see it . Can you upload your complete view and controller

Comment: Quick question, does it trigger for any one of file type or doesn't. For Instance if you try PDF to upload and then delete does it work?

Comment: No, its not triggering at all. (only when using lib 1.44)

Comment: Hi, can you copy paste the exact version of 1.44, you can check this in the console developer tools by writing sap.ui.version command.